# GitHub/Git Issues with overwrites and dup code in multi-serve port structure

Tags: laravel, git, apache, devops

this is sort of a top-level full stack question for someone who has some top-tier git knowledge(fluff up).

In our current projects environment we have a single dev server with a typical LAMP set up and building with Laravel, to handle 4 dev's working off a single server I setup a multi-site serving with apache, giving each dev their own port.  Each port directs to a folder that each dev works from, giving them all their own code base but one URL with port appendices.

Folder structure

```
/var/www/master_dev
/var/www/dev_1
/var/www/dev_2
```

etc.

Scenario basically goes, each dev has a port which they do their specified work in, when completed they create a branch and push, we check it, merge to the standard port 80 and test for bugs.

We're currently at git version 2.35.3, but for some unknown reason sometimes when we merge, there is dup data, sometimes old versions find their way in too.

Now some dev's auto format their HTML.  Some space differently. Some don't format anything and it's horrible.  But does that effect merging in anyway shape or form?

Is it the apache serving on different ports when pulling/pushing?  Each dev does a fresh pull from the master every morning (or should).

When git pulls is it intelligent enough to stay within the working directory it is requested from?

Is it possible that this is just human error?

A lot of questions I know but I'm starting to lose the will to live.

Exclaimer: yes I know of other approaches, i.e. local, containers, etc. etc.  I'm working on it, coming to this party late

Comment: Do you mean: You have those three folders committed to git at the same time, in the same repository?

Comment: All three folders pull/push from the same repo yes, if a dev has changes they create a new branch and then create a PR, once checked it's merged into the main branch and tested in the main web directory /var/www/master_dev

Comment: *But does that effect merging in anyway shape or form?* Yes! Git's merge algorithm is purely text-based and knows only "lines". Reformatting HTML will totally screw things up. Don't do it.